# Как можно отрефакторить этот кусок кода?

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, подскажите, как можно улучшить этот кода? либо разбить может его на более мелкие части?

```
public function upload(CreateUploadImageAction $createUploadImageAction, $file)
    {
        $image = Image::make($file);
        $filename = $this->getFileName($file->getClientOriginalName(), $file->getClientOriginalExtension());

        $data['filename'] = $filename;
        $data['path'] = config('filesystems.disks.s3.url') . '/' . $this->storagePath;

        foreach ($this->storageSizes as $key => $storageSize) {
            $imageResize = $image->resize($storageSize['width'], $storageSize['height'], function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });

            try {
                Storage::disk('s3')->put("{$this->storagePath}/{$key}/{$filename}", $imageResize->stream());
                $data['sizes'][] = $key;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        try {
            $query = $createUploadImageAction->handle(['path' => $data['path'], 'image' => $filename]);
            $data['id'] = $query->id;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: А с какой целью его рефакторить ? Выглядит хорошо, ничего лишнего, все что происходит сразу понятно. Да и небольшой он по размеру, сокращать смысла не вижу

Comment: 1. У вас идет создание файла, можно выносить в отдельную функцию.
2. Далее, обработка storageSizes, аналогично.
3. Ну и обработка ответа, нарисовывется название даже, что-то вроде handleUploadResult.

В итоге, получите контракт, на входе (CreateUploadImageAction $createUploadImageAction, $file) далее, создание файла, обработка размеров и обработка ответа (ответ возвращаем вызовом метода, чтобы сохранить следующий контракт (в функции upload, если декомпозируете, ответ модифицировать не должны)).